# Which way is the most efficient to define a empty String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, performance

I know 4 different types how to define an empty String in Swift.

1. `var newString = ""`
2. `var newString: String = ""`
3. `var newString: String = String()`
4. `var newString = String()`

Which way is the most efficient way when it comes to how fast the code gets executed?
Is there even a different between them?

Comment: I am not sure there is any runtime difference here, only compile time differences. But I have no idea if they are even measurable.

Comment: Don’t worry about stuff like this, difference is going to be pretty much none

Comment: I agree with both the comments above. In terms of which you should probably use, #1 is the most common way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only really two different techniques here:

- Using an empty string literal: `var newString = ""`
- Calling empty String initializer: `var newString = String()`

The other two are just these two techniques, but with an explicit type annotation. Type annotations are a compile-time only aspect of your program, which exist only to communicate types to the compiler, with no impact at run-time. In this case, both variables would have been inferred to be `String`*, so these type annotations are redundant, and don't tell the compiler anything you didn't already know.

These two approaches should have the exact same run-time characteristics.

The compiler can intern string constants to prevent repetitions of the same string literals from being repeated in the final application binary. This actually wouldn't be relevant here, because Swift uses tagged pointers to store "small strings" (IDR what exactly constitutes "small"), meaning don't even require heap allocation.

In a sense, that means that having a short string like `"abc"` in your code is no different than `123`. It's just a small value that's pushed onto the stack when you enter your function.

If you're coming from other languages, you might expect `String()` to result in a different instance on every call, but that isn't actually the case in Swift. There is no instance allocated at all, just an empty string as represented by the small-string storage, which is stored inline. The compiler should also be able to recognize that `String()` always results in the same value, which it should be able to inline, much like how `Int()` gets replaced with `0`.

---

* Actually, if you define a type named `StringLiteral` in your module, the inferred type of `""` will be your `StringLiteral` type rather than the default `String`.